# Difference between stream cipher and block cipher

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, algorithm-design, stream-cipher

I read that

> A typical stream cipher encrypts plaintext one byte at a time, although a stream cipher may be designed to operate on one bit at a time or on units larger than a byte at a time.

(Source: [Cryptography and Network Security](http://williamstallings.com/Cryptography/), William Stallings.)

A block cipher encrypts one block at a time. The block may be of size one byte or more or less. That means we can also encrypt a block of one byte by help of a stream cipher as a stream.

So, what exactly is the difference between a stream cipher and a block cipher?

Comment: IMHO many concepts/definitions are not exactly clear-cut but have boundaries in a sense rather fluid. They are used in the ways as such because they are convenient in discourse where commonly there are appropriate contexts to help more exact understanding. Hence  there are redundancies. I suppose a good analogy to the issue here is "a rich man" vs. "a poor man".

Comment: The first paragraph of the question appear to be copied word-for-word from *Cryptography and Network Security* (William Stallings, Section 6.3).  You must always attribute the source of any material that you copy from external sources; see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: A stream cipher may use or 'wrap' a block cipher. Eg AES SIC can be used to generate the keystream. The fact that the key stream is N times block size in length does not have any bearing on the length of cipher/plain texts

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A [**block cipher**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) is a deterministic and computable function of $k$-bit keys and $n$-bit (plaintext) blocks to $n$-bit (ciphertext) blocks. (More generally, the blocks don't have to be bit-sized, $n$-character-blocks would fit here, too). This means, when you encrypt the same plaintext block with the same key, you'll get the same result. (We normally also want that the function is invertible, i.e. that given the key and the ciphertext block we can compute the plaintext.)

To actually encrypt or decrypt a message (of any size), you don't use the block cipher directly, but put it into a [**mode of operation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation). The simplest such mode would be [electronic code book mode (ECB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29), which simply cuts the message in blocks, applies the cipher to each block and outputs the resulting blocks. (This is generally not a secure mode, though.)

Some early encryption schemes like the one used by Caesar could be categorized as a "block cipher with 1-character blocks in ECB-mode". Or generally, everything that has a *code book*.

We usually use other modes of operation, which include an **initialization vector** and some kind of feedback, so that every block of every message is encrypted a different way.

A [**stream cipher**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) is a function which directly maps $k$-bit keys and arbitrary length plaintexts to (same arbitrary length) ciphertext, in such a way that prefixes of the plaintext map to prefixes of the ciphertext, i.e. we can compute the starting part of the ciphertext before the trailing part of the plaintext is known.
(Often the message sizes might be limited to multiples of some "block size", too, but usually with smaller blocks like whole bytes or such.)

If a part of the plaintext repeats, the corresponding ciphertext usually is not the same – different parts of the message will be encrypted in different ways.

Often such stream ciphers work by producing a *keystream* from the actual key (and maybe an initialization vector) and then simply XOR-ing it with the message – these are called [**synchronous stream ciphers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher#Synchronous_stream_ciphers).  Other stream ciphers might vary the encryption of future parts of the message depending on previous parts.

Some block cipher modes of operation actually create a synchronous stream cipher, like [CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) and [OFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Output_feedback_.28OFB.29) mode.

You should never reuse a key (and IV, if applicable) of a synchronous stream cipher (which includes block ciphers in streaming modes) for different messages, since this can lead to compromises. (And even for the same message it will show that you repeated a message.)

Note that in actual usage you will also want a MAC, e.g. integrity protection, for your message. (Some schemes are broken in case of a chosen-ciphertext attack, for example, and such a MAC will prevent this (if you only pass the message to the decryptor after checking the MAC).)

Comment: When would you choose between a stream vs. block? Is there a difference in security? Or speed of encryption?

Comment: @anoopelias Block ciphers are generally slow as compared to Stream ciphers. Also, I am not sure but I think stream ciphers are good at providing information security while block ciphers are good at providingcomputational security

Comment: With regard to the last paragraph - would you please provide a link for an example in which adding a MAC protects against a chosen-ciphertext attack?

Answer (score 23):

Mathematically, a block cipher is just a keyed [pseudorandom permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) family on the set $\{0,1\}^n$ of $n$-bit blocks.  (In practice, we usually also require an efficient way to compute the inverse permutation.)  A block cipher *on its own* is not very useful for practical cryptography, at least unless you just happen to need to encrypt small messages that each fit into a single block.

However, it turns out that block ciphers are *extremely* versatile building blocks for constructing other cryptographic tools: once you have a good block cipher, you can easily build anything from stream ciphers to hash functions, message authentication codes, key derivation functions, pseudorandom number generators, entropy pools, etc. based on just one block cipher.

Not all of these applications necessarily *need* a block cipher; for example, many of them could be based on any [pseudorandom function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function) which need not be a permutation (but, conveniently, there's a [lemma](http://www.scribd.com/doc/59889516/29/The-PRP-PRF-switching-lemma) that says a pseudorandom permutation will, nonetheless, work).  Also, many of the constructions are indirect; for example, you can construct a key derivation function from a message authentication code, which you can construct from a hash function, which you can — but don't *have* to — construct from a block cipher.  But still, if you have a block cipher, you *can* build all the rest out of it.

Furthermore, these constructions typically come with (conditional) security proofs that reduce the security of the constructed functions to that of the underlying block cipher.  Thus, you don't need to carry out the laborious and unreliable task of cryptanalyzing each of these functions separately — instead, you're free to concentrate all your efforts on the block cipher, knowing that any confidence you'll have on the security of the block cipher directly translates into confidence on all the functions based on it.

Obviously, all this is very convenient if you're, say, working on a small embedded platform where including efficient and secure code for lots of separate crypto primitives could be difficult and expensive.  But even if you're not on such a constrained platform, writing and analyzing low-level crypto code can be laborious due to the need to pay attention to things like [side-channel attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack).  It's easier to restrict yourself to a limited number of low-level building blocks and to build everything you need out of those.

Also, even on fast platforms with lots of memory, like desktop CPUs, implementing low-level crypto operations directly in hardware can be much faster than doing them in software — but it's not practical to do that for more than a few of them.  Due to their versatility, block ciphers are excellent candidates for hardware implementation (as in the [AES instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) for modern x86 CPUs).

---

What about stream ciphers, then?

Mathematically, a [stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) — in the most general sense of the term — is also a keyed invertible pseudorandom function family, but on the set $\{0,1\}^*$ of arbitrary-length bitstrings rather than on blocks of limited length.

(There are some subtleties here; for example, most stream cipher constructions require the input to include a unique [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) value, and do not guarantee security — in the sense of indistinguishability from a truly random function — if the same nonce is used for two different inputs.  Also, as there is no uniform distribution on invertible functions from $\{0,1\}^*$ to itself to choose random functions from, we need to define carefully just what it means for a stream cipher to look "indistinguishable from random", and this definition *does* have practical security implications — for example, most stream ciphers leak the length of the message.  Practically, we usually also require that stream ciphers, in fact, be "streaming", in the sense that arbitrarily long input bitstreams can be encrypted — and decrypted — using only constant storage and time linear in the message length.)

Of course, stream ciphers are much more immediately useful than block ciphers: you can use them directly to encrypt messages of any length.  However, it turns out that they're also much *less* useful as building blocks for other cryptographic tools: if you have a block cipher, you can easily [turn it into a stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation), whereas turning an arbitrary stream cipher into a block cipher is [difficult if not impossible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/712/converting-a-stream-cipher-into-a-block-cipher).

So why do people bother designing dedicated stream ciphers at all, then, if block ciphers can do the job just as well?  Mostly, the reason is speed: sometimes, you need a fast cipher to encrypt lots of data, and there are some *really* fast dedicated stream cipher designs out there.  Some of these designs are also designed to be very compact to implement, either in software or hardware or both, so that if you really only need a stream cipher, you can save on code/circuit size by using one of those ciphers instead of a general block cipher based one.

However, what you gain in speed and compactness, you lose in versatility.  For example, there doesn't seem to be any simple way to [make a hash function out of a stream cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/can-you-make-a-hash-out-of-a-stream-cipher), so if you need one of those (and you often do, because hash functions, besides being useful on their own, are also common building blocks for other crypto tools), you'll have to implement them separately.  And, guess what, most hash functions are based on block ciphers, so if you have one, you might as well reuse the same block cipher for encryption too (unless you really need the raw speed of the dedicated stream cipher).

Comment: I questioned whether it is necessary to have two different terms. According to what you explained, a stream cipher is simply a special case of a block cipher, i.e. one for the limiting case where the n in the set {0,1}^n is 1. So I would argue for not maintaining the current distinction of terminologies.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Actually, a stream cipher is not simply a block cipher with block size 1 (other than classic monoalphabetic ciphers, which can be assumed to be both). A stream cipher usually translates the bits/bytes/... of the stream differently, depending on the current internal state of the cipher, while a block cipher for same input has same output (and thus is usually used in a "mode of operation" to create a stream cipher).

Comment: @PauloEbermann. IMHO you answered for me a question of CodesinChaos conscerning "dynamics and variability".

Comment: @Mok-KongShen No he didn't. The only advantage a dedicated stream cipher has over a block cipher in an appropriate mode is performance. You can't disregard chaining modes, since nobody sane uses block ciphers without appropriate chaining.

Comment: @CodesInChaos. Different applications have different performance requirements. To encrypt e.g. an email, one doesn't need the performance that would be desirable for encryption of, say, a video-file.

Comment: @CodesInChaos. Sorry I missed to answer your main point. I was referring to Ebermann's sentence "A stream cipher usually translates the bits/bytes/... of the stream differently, depending ...". Doesn't that "differently" correspond to the notion of variablity?

Answer (score 12):

A block cipher by itself does map `n` bits to `n` bits using a key. i.e. it's a keyed pseudo-random permutation. It cannot accept longer or shorter texts.

To actually encrypt a message you *always* need a chaining mode. ECB is one such chaining mode(and a really bad one), and it's not the pure block cipher. Even ECB consists of "add-on processing operations". These chaining modes can have quite different properties.

One of the most popular chaining modes, Counter mode (CTR) constructs a synchronous stream cipher from a block cipher. Another mode, CFB constructs a self synchronizing stream cipher, with properties somewhere between those of CBC and a synchronous stream cipher.

So your assumption that there are no ciphers between stream and blockciphers isn't really true. Cryptographers just prefer building them from the well understood block cipher primitive, instead of creating a completely new system.

I'd call Vigenère a stream cipher, albeit one with a much too short period. It uses a 26 symbol encoding instead of a 2 symbol encoding, but that doesn't mean it's not a stream cipher. Look at [Solitaire/Pontifex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitaire_%28cipher%29) for a modern construction of a stream cipher with 26 symbols.

Comment: If I don't err, "chaining" in block encryption is normally employed in the context of "block chaining", i.e. rendering the successive blocks dependent on one another so as to make the analysis more difficult. So IMHO ECB would have by definition no chaining effect as such.

Comment: You do err. A *good* chaining mode will have these properties, but bad modes still exist!

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic types of Encryption

1. Symmetric. It uses same key for encryption and Decryption.
2. Asymmetric. It uses two different keys(public and private) to encrypt and decrypt.

Block Cipher and Stream Cipher forms part of Symmetric Encryption. Stream Cipher generates a extended keystream from user given key and then XoR it with plaintext (for encryption) / ciphertext (for decryption).

Whereas Block Cipher takes a block of Data as input, run multiple rounds on it alongwith key mixing and produce Cipher Text. The Block Ciphers have various modes of operation out of which Counter(CTR) mode works similar to stream cipher. A sequential number is input to the block cipher, and its output is Xored with Plaintext to make Ciphertext. In this mode of operation only Encryption code of the block cipher is required. There is no need of decryption code, for decryption we simply input the same sequential number to block cipher, and Xored its output with Ciphertext to get Plain text. Sometime a nounce is used along with the Counter, so input the block cipher is split in two, i.e A Fixed nounce and Incremental Counter.

[image]

Other mode of operations are:-

1. ECB (provides Confidentiality)
2. CBC and CTR (provides Confidentiality and Sementically secure against Chosen Plaintext Attack)
3. EAX, CCM and GCM (provides authenticated Encryption)

More Detail Can be Found [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)