# Difference between statistical PRNG and cryptographic PRNG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, random-number-generator, lfsr

What's the difference between a statistical pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) and a cryptographic-strength PRNG?

I've seen a lot of PRNGs that are proposed for statistical uses -- e.g., statistical simulation, games, that sort of thing.  These statistical PRNGs include schemes like linear congruential generators, linear feedback shift registers (LFSR), Mersenne twister, and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

I've also seen many proposals for cryptographic-strength PRNGs: PRNGs designed for cryptographic uses.  These include constructions such as AES-CTR DRBG, HMAC_DRBG, ANSI X9.17, and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

What's the difference between these two kinds of PRNGs?  Is there any difference?

Can I take a PRNG that was designed for statistical use, and use it for cryptographic purposes?  Would that be safe?  If I find some statistical PRNG that looks nifty but wasn't designed specifically for cryptographic use, would it be reasonable to use it for cryptographic uses?  What if I start with a statistical PRNG and then tweak it a little bit -- would it be OK then?

<sub>This is intended as a general reference question that we can point others to, when they ask about specific instances of this sort situation.</sub>