# New Cryptographic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design

I was wondering about an algorithm that would take a bitstring as an input, shuffle it and output it. You could use a deterministic RNG to select pairs of bits to swap, using the seed as some sort of password, handing it to people to let them reconstruct the shuffling process. Is this a good idea? Has anyone already thought of this? If not, are there any flaws I would have to bear in mind?
I'm a newbie to cryptography and I don't really know how to approach this.

Excuse my poor English grammar and thank you for your time!

EDIT: I forgot to specify that this is for learning purposes.

Comment: What exactly do you want with that?

Comment: No, nobody has yet thought of a transposition cipher.

Comment: Transposition is a rather important part of ciphers. However, because it obviously leaks information at least on the values of the separate bits, it is not used *on it's own* in modern ciphers. Still, transposition is important for creating the avalanche effect to achieve confusion and diffusion. There are some terms to lookup for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They call this a [transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher) cipher.  Bits commonly have more semantic meaning assembled into characters and numbers, so you may be performing  [fractionation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher#Fractionation) specifically.  Also, in cryptography we'd use a [CSPRNG](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12436/what-is-the-difference-between-csprng-and-prng) for the shuffle rather than a plain RNG for invertability reasons detailed in the link.     [Frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) means that it's fairly easy to break though.  Stuff to think about then.

It's a lot to take in, and there are very subtle nuances that mean creating a cipher from scratch is pretty tough. It's [better](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged) to stick to library functions/ standardised methods /primitives in non scholarly uses.   Hi!