# Will repeated rounds of SHA-512 provide random numbers?

Tags: hash

If I hash a keyword with SHA-512 and then feed the output as the key for the next round ....and keep repeating this process, will I gather a stream of random numbers?

Comment: pseudorandom yes, depending on your use of the outputs, the method you described may be a massive security risk

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-it-feasible-to-build-a-stream-cipher-from-a-cryptographic-hash-function describes some of the problems you may run into with schemes like this.

Answer (score 14):

For an adversary **not** knowing the definition of SHA-512 (or just not knowing the 512-bit initialization constant of SHA-512, defined as *the first sixty-four bits of the fractional parts of the square roots of the first eight prime numbers*), the sequence obtained by
$$\begin{align*}
H_0&=\text{SHA-512}(Seed){\small\text{ where }}Seed{\small\text{ is the statement's keyword}}\\
H_{i+1}&=\text{SHA-512}(H_i)\\
\end{align*}$$
is a [Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG) as far as we know. It is in practice indistinguishable from random for said adversary, with residual odds of the contrary less than $2^{-100}$, assuming a few additional requirements:

1. Less than $2^{200}$ outputs are available to the adversary [rationale: *if* it happens that the generator enters a cycle, *then* the adversary can predict future output, including with feasibly little memory; after about $2^{(512-100+1)/2}$ iterations of a random function with 512-bit output, odds of cycling are about $2^{-100}$; I kept some margin]. Notice that producing even the first $2^{60}$ outputs would take at least five years with current technology, because this RNG and SHA-512 are a serial process [estimate based on two gate delays each one [picosecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picosecond) per round].
2. This adversary uses classical computing means bound to perform less work than needed for $2^{250}$ hash computations (a safe assumption), or anything that I can fantasize today (your call) [rationale: the best explicit attack I have enumerates the SHA-512 initialization values, and that reaches odds $2^{-100}$ to succeed at about $2^{412}$ hashes; I kept a helluva of margin]; Note: 1 and 2 can be combined into *the adversary can not perform the classical-computing equivalent of counting to $2^{200}$*, which is still very credible.
3. $Seed$ is never reused.
4. The adversary does not obtain the SHA-512 specification (including initialization value) by some oblique mean: reverse engineering, operating goof, spying (including bribery and planting trojans), [rubber hose cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis), [side channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack).. [Note: reading the [official specification](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf) was discounted in the first sentence].

---

However, with respect to an adversary knowing the full definition of SHA-512 (which is the assumption a cryptographer will make by [Kerckhoffs's principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)), the generator is unsafe. In particular, $H_j$ for $j>i$ can be trivially predicted from $H_i$; the generator fails the [next bit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-bit_test).

---

In addition, from a practical perspective, the generator is very bad by the mere fact that it is simultaneously

- deterministic;
- without another key than a *keyword* presumably of low entropy;
- without provision for [key streching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) to slow keyword enumeration.

If the keyword is simple enough to be reliably memorized in a real application by a majority of adult humans, then password cracking can quickly find the keyword by enumeration knowing say 10 bytes of $H_0$.

---

So all in all, the generator is secure for some non-cryptographic applications like numerical simulations, and disastrous from the perspectives on-topic here.

Comment: But if published result of each SHA512 invocation is just first 256 or 128 bit, then it should be safe. Ie Si = SHA512(Si-1), Hi = first256bit(Si) .

Comment: Then it could be extended with mixing seed every time: Si = SHA512(Si-1 || Seed)

Comment: And then it could be extended with mixing both Seed and iteration number: Si = SHA512(Si-1 || Seed || i)

Answer (score 5):

The definition of "random" is something not very clear that deserves some more explanation, like what you expect from the output number sequence.

- If you want an uniformed distributed sequence you will get it.
- If you want an unpredictable sequence you won't.
- If you want a "sequence undistinguishable from random" you won't get it either.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the sequence is **not** uniformly distributed: it will ultimately enter a cycle (that's expected after roughly $2^{256}$ hashes), and it is extremely unlikely that the mean number of $1$ in this cycle is exactly $1/2$, a requirement for any uniformly distributed ultimately cyclic sequence.