# Is my method symmetric encryption?

Tags: block-cipher, algorithm-design, symmetric, stream-cipher

To obfuscate data I made up this method on the spot without planning since the goal wasn't real encryption.

At first I though this cannot be real encryption but after revisiting the code and reading on block symmetric encryption, and including R in the method, it seems that it is( looks like a stream cypher, OFB specifically ).

The method is the following( pseudo code ):

-Hash function parameters, secret key, hash and array elements all have the same size in bits. 
-Size is at least 128 bits for this example. 
-Using a cryptographic random generator.

H - cryptographic hash function 
K - secret key, randomly generated 
A - array of plaintext 
L - array length 
R - randomly generated, is not encrypted and is stored with the resulting encrypted data

```
keyhash = H(K)
hash = R
for( i , i < L , i++ )
{
    hash = H( hash ^ keyhash )
    A[i] ^= hash
}
```

Could this be called encryption or it has some fundamental flaws that would break it immediately?

Comment: Don't you mean $C_i = A_i \oplus h$? Otherwise you don't have ciphertext ;)

Comment: Of course, `^` is XOR in Java as well, but above you've only defined the plaintext. Now it's also the ciphertext after the operation.

Answer (score 2):

Your scheme is indeed an instance of output feedback mode (OFB), using
$$(\mathit{key},\mathit{pad}) \mapsto H(\mathit{key}\oplus\mathit{pad})\text,$$
where $\mathit{key}$ corresponds to `keyhash` and $\mathit{pad}$ to `hash`, as the "block cipher". (It is very likely not really a block cipher due to lack of bijectivity, but that's not needed for output feedback mode.) When $H$ is a cryptographically  secure hash function, the construction should have the same security properties as OFB using a "real" block cipher; however, since hash functions are usually slower than block ciphers, one generally prefers to use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a bitstream and XORing it with your plaintext so yes, it is. More precisely, it's a block cipher. Have a look at a previous [discussion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-it-feasible-to-build-a-stream-cipher-from-a-cryptographic-hash-function).